# Something like a game engine but for simple apps

Tags: google-maps, game-engine

Is there any engine that isn't for games that lets you create apps with buttons and text and Google Maps locations etc?

Comment: Basically any programming language?

Comment: I mean more of an drag and drog interface and that it can be used on both android and iphone without making two different apps

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually there is:

[https://codiqa.com](https://codiqa.com/)

You can build there jQuery Mobile apps that would run on both systems.
It is basically a web app, but it suites your needs.

You can use there Google Maps and create location based apps.